# Neo4j:Get every node with specified parent child variable

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Here is an example of graph

```
-Task
       -Sub task 1
       -Sub task 2    
          -Sub task 2-1
          -Sub task 2-2
```

I need result like

```
{
Task,
children : [{
             Sub task 1,
             children : [{
                    Sub task 2-1
                    Sub task 2-2
                    }]
           }]
}
```

How can i do this by using cypher, please tell if i need to elaborate more.

Thanks

Comment: i think your requirement is 
`(:Task)-[:HAS_SUB_TASK]->(:Task)-[:HAS_SUB_TASK]->(:Task)`

Comment: Yes it is, but i need data in specified format

Comment: It should be possible to roll up your results into JSON format (I'll see if I can work on an answer demonstrating this). However, your desired format is not JSON, in that you have free-floating values in your objects rather than key/values. I don't think that will work from Cypher or APOC procedures, you would need to modify the returned values in some way, or go with JSON output instead.

Comment: Yes i need json in that, suppose i have one field named "task name" in task and sub task.

Comment: I am guessing you have a View component that accepts data in this format. I needed this too, at some point. You should write an APOC query that returns data in this format, or do some post-processing on the client.